# Executing elm-test throws runtime exception: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined

Tags: elm, elm-test

The following test results in a runtime exception:

```
test "search yields profile" <|
\_ ->
    let
        -- Setup
        location =
            Navigation.Location "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""

        ( model, _ ) =
            Home.init location

        -- Test
        ( newState, _ ) =
            model |> Home.update (Search "Scott")

        -- Verify
        ( onlyOne, isContentProvider1 ) =
            ( (newState.contentProviders |> List.length) == 1
            , newState.contentProviders |> List.member contentProvider1
            )
    in
        Expect.equal (onlyOne && isContentProvider1) True
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined
    at Object.getLocation (eval at <anonymous> (my_path\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\elm-test\lib\runner.js:84:37),
<anonymous>:1392 6:17)
    at Function.eval (eval at <anonymous> (my_path\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\elm-test\lib\runner.js:84:37),
<anonymous>:14127:43)
    at A2 (eval at <anonymous> (my_path\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\elm-test\lib\runner.js:84:37),
<anonymous>:92:11)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (my_path\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\elm-test\lib\runner.js:84:37),
<anonymous>:21270:31)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (my_path\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\elm-test\lib\runner.js:84:37),
<anonymous>:22757:4)
    at my_path\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\elm-test\lib\runner.js:84:32
    at Object.evalElmCode (my_path\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\elm-test\lib\runner.js:84:76)
    at my_path\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\elm-test\bin\elm-test:196:14
    at my_path\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\elm-test\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at tryToString (fs.js:456:3)
```

My hunch is that the *Navigaton.Location* is behind the exception. However, I have no clue how to resolve the issue.

The source code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Lambda-Cartel/Nikeza).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you've found an answer to this on Elm Slack, but I've spent some time looking into this and have found the cause of the problem.

In short, the problem is including your call to `Navigation.program` in an Elm file that gets run using elm-test.  In your case, `Navigation.program` is in `Home.elm`.  Move it to a different module (or temporarily comment it out) and your tests should run.

In more detail, the native code behind [`Navigation.program`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/navigation/latest/Navigation#program) gets `document.location` and passes that into your `init` function.  However, when running elm-test, you don't have a `document` object as there isn't a browser.  elm-test will make up a skeletal `document` object instead, but this object has no `location` property and hence an exception is thrown attempting to get `location.href`.

There is some guidance to this effect in the [elm-test](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/elm-test/latest) package documentation (point 1 under 'Application-specific techniques'):

> Avoid importing your `Main` module. Most of your code belongs in other modules, so import those instead.

---

Alternatively, [`document.location` has now been polyfilled](https://github.com/rtfeldman/node-test-runner/issues/213) in elm-test version 0.18.9, so upgrading to that version will also fix this problem.